# Getting NaN for variables in Node.js.. Arg?

Tags: node.js

ok, I have a homework assignment where I have to read in files and calculate the distance between a bunch of numbers in the files and then print out the mean and standard deviation of each set of numbers.  The end of the script, where the console.log stuff is, is giving all NaN for the variables.  Can anyone help me out?

*I've omitted repeating parts of the script to make it shorter (their are more arrays than just the lHipJoint array and the calculations for them but I left them out).

```
var fs = require('fs');

var lHipJoint = new Array();

//open the first text file

fs.readFile('file.txt','utf8', function (err, data)
{
    if (err) throw err;

    //split the data into an array with each line as an element
    stuff=data.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
    {
        //function that processes each line into an array
        //with each number as an element and does the euclidean dis.
        processLine(stuff[i]);
    }
    data.length = 0;
    stuff.length = 0;
});


//do the same for the next file
fs.readFile('file2.txt','utf8', function (err, data)
{
    if (err) throw err;
    stuff=data.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
    {

      processLine(stuff[i]);
    }
    data.length = 0;
    stuff.length = 0;
});

//and again
fs.readFile('file3.txt','utf8', function (err, data)
{
    if (err) throw err;
    stuff=data.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
    {

      processLine(stuff[i]);
    }
    data.length = 0;
    stuff.length = 0;
});

//and again
fs.readFile('file4.txt','utf8', function (err, data)
{
    if (err) throw err;
    stuff=data.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
    {

      processLine(stuff[i]);
    }
    data.length = 0;
    stuff.length = 0;
});

//and again
fs.readFile('file5.txt','utf8', function (err, data)
{
    if (err) throw err;
    stuff=data.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
    {

      processLine(stuff[i]);
    }
    data.length = 0;
    stuff.length = 0;
});

//and again
fs.readFile('file6.txt','utf8', function (err, data)
{
    if (err) throw err;
    stuff=data.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
    {

      processLine(stuff[i]);
    }
    data.length = 0;
    stuff.length = 0;
});

//function to split each line into an array with each number as an element
//then parse the number strings into floats and do the euclidean distances,
//storing the values in arrays for each bone.
function processLine(line)
{
    var line1 = line
    var numbers = line1.split(" ");
    line1.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        var number = parseFloat(numbers[i]);
        line1[i] = number[i];
    }
        lHipJoint = Math.sqrt((line1[6] - line1[9])*(line1[6] - line1[9]) + (line1[7] - line1[10])*(line1[7] - line1[10]) + (line1[8] - line1[11])*(line1[8] - line1[11]));

    //reset the arrays so they can be reused
    line1.length = 0;
    numbers.length = 0;
    number.length = 0;
}

//calculations and output for the mean and SD of each bone's distance from the root bone.
for(var i = 0; i < lHipJoint.length; i++)
{
    var lHipJointTotal = lHipJointTotal + lHipJoint[i];
}

var lHipJointMean = lHipJointTotal/lHipJoint.length;

for(var i = 0; i < lHipJoint.length; i++)
{
    var lHipJointSDSum = lHipJointSDSum + (lHipJoint[i] - lHipJointMean)*(lHipJoint[i] - lHipJointMean);
}

var lHipJointSD = Math.sqrt(lHipJointSDSum/lHipJoint.length);

console.log("The mean distance of the left hip joint from the root bone is " +lHipJointMean+ " and the standard deviation is " +lHipJointSD+ ".\n");
```

Comment: Normally in Node.js you want to use all async IO, but in your case it's not needed since you're doing a one time read some files and output some text.   Switching to fs.readFileSync should clear things up.  Your console.log is running before the files have finished reading.

Comment: So all I need to do is change all instances of readFile to readFileSync?

Comment: If all I had to do was change readFile to readFileSync to make it synchronous, that didn't clear up the NaN problem :/

Comment: Hint : Check the type of `line1` in `processLine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a lot of strange things here in your script i will try to
bring upp as manny as i can.

So first of all dont reset arrays. 
your in a garbage collected language just reallocate new ones.

Also in the processLine function you are assigning numbers to the indexes of a string
i asume you think its an array but its not the same thing. 
strings are immutable (cant be changed) in javascript.

In the aggregating for loops att the bottom of the file you are
declaring the variable in every iteration. you want to declare it before the loop like this.

```
var x = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
 x = x + ......
}
```

Your cals to read the files all do the same thing.
So you want to use the same function for that.
write it ones.

You are assigning to the lHipJoint array in the 
processLine function my understanding is that you want to add
the calculated value to the array.
You can do this with the push method like this

```
lHipJoint.push(Math.sqr(........
```

Also theres a problem with using the async file reading
sins your printing the result before you even read the files.
if you want to use the async ones you need to coordinate so that.
you only print the result when you done all the file reading.
but a tips is to use the non async ones in this case.

I understand this is an assignment so you might not want to read my 
attempt to correct the program beneath.

Maybe read it after you handed in yours, but im leaving it here 
for the q&a reference for others reading this.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var filePaths = ["file.txt", "file2.txt", 
                  "file3.txt", "file4.txt", 
                  "file5.txt", "file6.txt"];

var lHipJoint = [];

filePaths.forEach(function(path) {
  var content  = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf-8");
  var lines = content.split("\n");
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    if(line.trim() === "") return;
    var numbers = line.split("\t").map(parseFloat);
    // im not touching your calculation :D
    lHipJoint.push(Math.sqrt((numbers[6] - numbers[9])*(numbers[6] - numbers[9]) 
      + (numbers[7] - numbers[10])*(numbers[7] - numbers[10]) + (numbers[8] - numbers[11])
        *  (numbers[8] - numbers[11])));
  });
});

var lHipJointTotal = lHipJoint.reduce(function(p, c) {
  return p + c;
});
var lHipJointMean = lHipJointTotal / lHipJoint.length;
var lHipJointSDSum = lHipJoint.reduce(function(p, c) {
  return p + (c - lHipJointMean) * (c - lHipJointMean);
}, 0);
var lHipJointSD = Math.sqrt(lHipJointSDSum/lHipJoint.length);
console.log("The mean distance of the left hip joint from the root bone is " 
             + lHipJointMean + " and the standard deviation is " + lHipJointSD + ".\n");
```

there might be some error in this program i dont know how the data looks but i hope this helps
you.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm just starting out with JS so I'm not really familiar with a lot of the methods, including .forEach. It really makes things easier (and cleaner).  However, I tried out your code just to see if it fixed the NaN problem, but its still doing it. . .  I'm so frustrated.

Comment: the most likly error seams to be if the data ither isent structured as space seperated floats ... witch the data presumes or theres not actualy lines in your data.
You are dividing by the length of lHipJoint so if thats 0 you getting Nan.

there dosent seam to be any division in the pushed algoritm so it should be one of those.

obs! the way NaN works is that if you have a NaN then all numeric operations on it will result in NaN

Comment: i dont think i can help you more without the data.

Comment: nope, its floats separated by commas with 99 floats per line.  the numbers get to the variable 'numbers' inside the function(line) but outside of that, numbers is undefined.  also the numbers are out of order.  Is the .map method doing that?  If I do a console.log(numbers[0]) inside the function, I get numbers.  If I do console.log(numbers[1]) i get undefined...

Comment: no its maintaining the order .... the numbers var is not available outside the scope of the function ... notice that its defined manny times one time for each line in every file.

Comment: the by commas part is not what the parseFloat is expecting it shuld be seperated by dot

Comment: oh, sorry, I meant spaces, not commas

Comment: if you write console.log(numbers) instead can you pase what you get from the console? .... inside the function that is . after numbers is declared

Comment: [ 9.9157 ]
[ 9.9297 ]
[ 9.9455 ]
[ 9.9673 ]
[ 9.9854 ]
[ 9.9946 ]
[ 9.9934 ]
[ 9.9912 ]
[ 10.002 ]
[ 10.015 ]
[ 10.011 ]
[ 10 ]
[ 9.9987 ]
[ 10.004 ]
[ 10.002 ]
[ 9.9946 ]
[ 9.9983 ]
[ 9.9968 ]
[ 9.9746 ]
[ 9.9668 ]
[ 9.958 ]
[ 9.9557 ]
[ 9.9542 ]
[ 9.9582 ]
[ 9.9671 ]
[ 9.9703 ]
[ 9.969 ]
[ 9.9688 ]
[ 9.9781 ]
[ 9.9931 ]
[ 9.9986 ]
[ 10.001 ]
[ 10.015 ]
[ 10.027 ]
[ 10.026 ]
[ 10.029 ]
[ 10.054 ]
[ 10.059 ]
[ 10.068 ]
[ 10.073 ]
[ 10.076 ]
[ 10.084 ]
[ 10.097 ]
[ NaN ] every once in a while a NaN will come up. but not all the numbers get spit out and they're not in order

Comment: so its only getting one float per line .... i think i need to se the data file are you shore there separated by space?

Comment: can I send you one of the text files?  maybe that will help

Comment: so from just reading the file they seem to be seperated by tab ('\t')

Comment: so i modified the code above and the result im getting now is this. The mean distance of the left hip joint from the root bone is 3.043720689158142 and the standard deviation is 2.2230198813222266.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much!  Two little characters made such a big difference.  Thanks again